# How can I find all games between 2 specific players?

Tags: database

How can I find all games played by 2 specific players?

For example: Nigel Short and Magnus Carlsen.

Is there some official FIDE database or something like that?

I'd like an easy way to see things like:

1. Their overall score against each other
2. A list of the games that make up this score, each with a link to the PGN of the game, showing date and tournament location etc
3. Most recent game played

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.chessgames.com. Just write "Short" and "Carlsen" in the search box.

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=&playercomp=either&pid=&player=short&pid2=&player2=carlsen&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=&eco=&result=

**EDIT**

Response to @Ywapom, Chessgames is quite good for top chess players like Carlsen. However, it can be incomplete for non top players. I'd suggest the expensive Mega Chessbase database.

Comment: chessgames.com is just one incomplete source of many.  You won't necessarily find all their games there.

Comment: @Ywapom The database is quite good for top players, such as Carlsen. It's only incomplete for non-top players.

Comment: Agreed that it is a decent source for top players, also that the mega chessbase db is probably the most complete.  However maybe chessgames.com won't have a game of Carlsen vs. Short when Carlsen was a lower rated kid.